On Emmy Noether's work on invariants of ternary biquadratic forms
It has been mentioned that Emmy Noether's thesis found's 331 invariants of ternary biquadratic forms (e.g. http://cwp.library.ucla.edu/articles/noether.asg/noether.html). The thesis can be found at https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1908.134.23/html. Here are some doubts on that:

What does it mean by "ternary biquadratic forms"? What's the difference between it and "degree-4 polynomial on 3 variables"?
And what does it mean by invariants? My understand is, consider the ring of coefficients $R=\mathbb{C}[a_{004},\dots,a_{400}]$, the polynomial is $\sum_{i+j+k=4}a_{ijk}x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k$. And $R$ has a natural $G=\mathop{\mathrm{SL}}_3(\mathbb{C})$ action. We are looking for generators of $R^{G}$, which is finite by Hilbert's work. But in the first section she talks about a specific polynomial $x_1^3x_2 + x_2^3x_3+x_3^3x_1$, and $R^{G}$ does not make sense for a specific polynomial, so what does invariants really mean?
It has been mentioned that the list are possibly incomplete, are there further works?


Emmy Noether, "Über die Bildung des Formensystems der ternären biquadratischen Form." Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, Vol. 134, No. 1, 1908, pp. 23-90 + 2 tables (scan). The number of 331 ternary biquadratic forms is the sum of the number of forms in different systems that Noether lists on p. 90.


The ternary biquadratic forms is a homogeneous degree-4 polynomial on 3 variables.



In her work, she examines not only the invariants whose definition you provided, but also more general constructions - covariants and contravariants, which can be polynomials of variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

